# out of memory with picturebox

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, picturebox

I am getting a out of memory every time I try to add a picture to a picture box

I have tried doing a dispose at the beginning of it but it still just gives me out of memory when I try to add a image from file

```
public void water(string path,string oupath)
{

    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
    Font myfont = new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    // Calculate the size of the text
    string waterString = waterText.Text;
    SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(waterString, myfont);
    // drawing position (X,Y)
    Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    int X;
    int Y;
    //Set the drawing position based on the users
    //selection of placing the text at the bottom or top of the image
    X = (int)(pictureBox1.Image.Width - sz.Width) / 2;
    Y = (int)(pictureBox1.Image.Height - sz.Height);
    // draw the water mark text
    g.DrawString(waterString, myfont, myBrush, new Point(X, Y));
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
    path = oupath+"/"+filename;
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"path",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You dispose the image, but you do not dispose any of the other disposable objects that you create, `g`, `myFont` and I think `myBrush` are all disposable too.

Comment: Also, why do you have `pictureBox1` at all, you can do the entire method without it.

Comment: While this is true, those other obejcts are really small and while not disposing of them will evntaully lead to gdi handle problems this will only happens after a lot of calls. And if all you want are standard brushes why not go for them. Do learn about `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromOmage(..)` etc..

Comment: Also: Since you are trying to save to the same image file you just loaded you may get a false exception. Try to save to a different name! which line exactly i it that throws?

Comment: Ok, so I can add the dispose of the objects and add some text to the saved file, That still doesn't fix that at the beginning picturebox1.Image gives me the out of memory exception before any of the the other stuff even gets to run